# docker with tensorflow gpu - ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, tensorflow, docker-compose, nvidia, nvidia-docker

Im trying to run docker with tensorflow using Nvidia GPUs, however when I run my container I get the following error:

```
pgp_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
pgp_1  |   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
pgp_1  |     from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
pgp_1  |   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
pgp_1  |     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
pgp_1  |   File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
pgp_1  |     _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
pgp_1  |   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
pgp_1  |     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
pgp_1  |   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
pgp_1  |     return _load(spec)
pgp_1  | ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Docker-compose**

My docker compose file looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  pgp:
    devices:
    - /dev/nvidia0
    - /dev/nvidia1
    - /dev/nvidia2
    - /dev/nvidia3
    - /dev/nvidia4
    - /dev/nvidiactl
    - /dev/nvidia-uvm
    image: "myimg/pgp"
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    environment:
     - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/cuda/lib64/
     - GPU_DEVICE=4
     - NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
     - NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
    volumes:
     - ./train_package:/opt/app-root/src/train_package
     - /usr/local/cuda/lib64/:/opt/local/cuda/lib64/
```

As you can see, I have tried having a volume to map host cuda to the docker container but this didnt help.

I am able to successfully run `nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi`

## Versions

**Cuda**

cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt shows CUDA Version 9.0.176

**nvcc -V**

nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176

**nvidia-docker version**

NVIDIA Docker: 2.0.3
Client:
 Version:   17.12.1-ce

API version:   1.35

Go version:    go1.9.4

Git commit:    7390fc6
 Built: Tue Feb 27 22:17:40 2018

OS/Arch:   linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  17.12.1-ce

API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)

Go version:   go1.9.4

Git commit:   7390fc6

Built:    Tue Feb 27 22:16:13 2018

OS/Arch:  linux/amd64

Experimental: false

**Tensorflow**

1.5 with gpu support, via pip

```
ldconfig -p | grep cuda
libnvrtc.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc.so.9.0
libnvrtc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc.so
libnvrtc-builtins.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc-builtins.so.9.0
libnvrtc-builtins.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc-builtins.so
libnvgraph.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvgraph.so.9.0
libnvgraph.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvgraph.so
libnvblas.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvblas.so.9.0
libnvblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvblas.so
libnvToolsExt.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvToolsExt.so.1
libnvToolsExt.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvToolsExt.so
libnpps.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnpps.so.9.0
libnpps.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnpps.so
libnppitc.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppitc.so.9.0
libnppitc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppitc.so
libnppisu.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppisu.so.9.0
libnppisu.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppisu.so
libnppist.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppist.so.9.0
libnppist.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppist.so
libnppim.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppim.so.9.0
libnppim.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppim.so
libnppig.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppig.so.9.0
libnppig.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppig.so
libnppif.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppif.so.9.0
libnppif.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppif.so
libnppidei.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppidei.so.9.0
libnppidei.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppidei.so
libnppicom.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppicom.so.9.0
libnppicom.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppicom.so
libnppicc.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppicc.so.9.0
libnppicc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppicc.so
libnppial.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppial.so.9.0
libnppial.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppial.so
libnppc.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppc.so.9.0
libnppc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppc.so
libicudata.so.55 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55
libcusparse.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so.9.0
libcusparse.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so
libcusolver.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so.9.0
libcusolver.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so
libcurand.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.0
libcurand.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so
libcuinj64.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcuinj64.so.9.0
libcuinj64.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcuinj64.so
libcufftw.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufftw.so.9.0
libcufftw.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufftw.so
libcufft.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufft.so.9.0
libcufft.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufft.so
libcudart.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.9.0
libcudart.so.7.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.7.5
libcudart.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so
libcudart.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so
libcuda.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
libcuda.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
libcublas.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.9.0
libcublas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so
libaccinj64.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libaccinj64.so.9.0
libaccinj64.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libaccinj64.so
libOpenCL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so.1
libOpenCL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so
```

### Tests with Tensorflow on Docker vs host

The following works, when running on the host:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.GIT_VERSION, tf.VERSION)"

v1.5.0-0-g37aa430d84 1.5.0
```

## Run container

`nvidia-docker run -d --name testtfgpu -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu`

## Log in

`nvidia-docker exec -it testtfgpu bash`

## Test Tensorflow version

`pip show tensorflow-gpu` shows:

`pip show tensorflow-gpu
Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 1.6.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: astor, protobuf, gast, tensorboard, six, wheel, absl-py, backports.weakref, termcolor, enum34, numpy, grpcio, mock`

### Python 2

`python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.GIT_VERSION, tf.VERSION)"`

Results in:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

### Python 3

`python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.GIT_VERSION, tf.VERSION)"`

Results in:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.GIT_ 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: Did you try to install this way, pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu?

Answer (score 1):

The problem because of your cuDNN version. Tensorflow-GPU 1.5 version will support cuDNN 7.0._ version. You can download that from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.0.5/prod/9.0_20171129/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7). Make sure that your CUDA version 9.0._ and cuDNN version 7.0._ . Please refer link in [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) for more details.

Comment: How can I check which version of cuDNN installed? Also, the the link that you provide - the url - contains `v7.0.5` and `cudnn-9.0` - so I am confused about which version I should have, and which version I am getting.

Comment: If you are using tensorflow 1.5 it will support to CUDA 9.0._. But you have to chose correct cuDNN version v7.0.5 or v7.0.4 should support.

Comment: I am using TF 1.5. How do I find out which version of cuDNN I have installed. And thanks for your help.

Comment: You do not want to find cuDNN version just download v7.0.4 and extract and copy and paste to CUDA folder as they mention in site. I used CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN v7.1._ but it not work and then I changed cuDNN version to v7.0.4 after it was working find.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a conflict between CUDA's version and TensorFlow's

First, try to check your CUDA version with one of the commands such as `nvcc --version` or `cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt`

If that's 8.x, you may need to reinstall CUDA or simpler, downgrade TensorFlow to 1.4. Otherwise, if your CUDA is 9.x, you need TensorFlow 1.5 or newer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Dong, I've updated my post with the versions. I am using TF1.5 that should support nvidia 9.

Comment: I see your log says that it's CUDA 7.5, right?
I have a training server with CUDA 8.0, I just tried to replace tensorflow-gpu 1.4 with 1.5 and got the same error as your:
https://i.imgur.com/0rmz2Ds.png

In another server I have CUDA 9.0, it works with TensorFlow 1.5 as well:
https://i.imgur.com/P7m0EW7.png

So, I still would like to suggest you to try several different versions of tensorflow-gpu to see which one works. As my experience:
- TF 1.4 works with CUDA 8.0
- TF 1.5 and 1.6 work with CUDA 9.0
- Nothing work with CUDA 9.1, I've installed it at first, then removed.

Comment: I have cuda-9.0 installed. But `nvcc -V` shows release 7. Are you suggesting that nvcc should be version 9?

Comment: Something went wrong with your installation. At first time deal with CUDA, I was also confused with it much. Your path looks odd. Not Debian? You may try something like
`cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt` to see which output?

Comment: `cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt` shows `CUDA Version 9.0.176`.

Comment: If so I have no more idea. However I never run them in docker.